# Spark without HDFS in cluster mode: Which data is stored where?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.5 without HDFS in cluster mode to build an application. I was wondering, when having a saving operation, e.g.,

```
df.write.parquet("...")
```

which data is stored where? Is all the data stored at the master, or is each worker storing its local data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking all workers nodes will perform writes to its local file system with driver writing only a `_SUCCESS` file.